# Your app crashed on iPad running iOS 8.4.1 iPhone running iOS 8.4.1

Tags: ios

So I have submitted my first app but I am getting it rejected with the following message:
2.1 Details During review, your app crashed on iPad running iOS 8.4.1 iPhone running iOS 8.4.1 when we:Specifically, the app crashes

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have any crash log?

Comment: No. When I test the app in xcode I have no problem. But how do I know if I am testing the app using IOS 8.4.1?

Comment: My base sdk is iOS 8.4 and the deployment target is 7.0

Comment: you should update your SDKs and integrate criticism for log crash

Comment: the SDK is set to the latest(iOS 8.4) - when typing in manually 8.4.1 it is not found

Comment: Apple should have sent you crash reports with their rejection. Start there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the resources, get access to an iPad running iOS 8.4.1 and an iPhone running iOS 8.4.1 and test them. Especially the last two years, the emulator has gotten less and less effective at duplicating real device functionality.